# How create file in C++ in a specific place in the PC

Tags: c++, file

Hey all, I have a problem, I don't know how to create a file in C++ in a specific place in the PC. For example a file (.txt) in C:\file.txt. Can anybody help me? Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  ofstream ofs("c:\\file.txt");
  if (ofs) {
     ofs << "hello, world!\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably fooling you because it's easier than you think.  You just open a file for create and give it that path name.  Voila.

[See](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/), eg,

```
// fstream::open
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

  fstream filestr;

  // You need a doubled backslash in a C string
  filestr.open ("C:\\file.txt", fstream::out);

  // >> i/o operations here <<

  filestr.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

....
FILE *file;
file = fopen("c:/file.txt", "w");
```

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the backslash?

Comment: @David: There will be a warning -- unknown escape character '\f' with this fopen statement.

Comment: Also isn't stdio c-style c++?